# TypeScript: Parametric collection and inheritance

Tags: typescript

I'm migrating a codebase from JS to TypeScript. I'm having some trouble designing a situation like this:

Suppose a Room class:

```
class Room {
   protected playersById : PlayerDict<Player>;

   getIds() {
      _.map(this.playersById, (p : Player) => { return p.getId() })
   }

   getFirst() {
      return _.first(this.playersById);
   }
}
```

And a subclass of Room called RoomGame

```
class RoomGame extends Room {
   protected playersById : PlayerDict<PlayerGame>;

   someMethod() {
      var player = this.getFirst();
      player.getB(); // Error because player if of type `Player` not `PlayerGame`
   }
}
```

How Can I resolve this situation on `someMethod` where what I want is the first item of the collection `playersById` of type `PlayerGame`. I tried to use Generic Classes but if I do `Room<GenericType>` I can't write functions like `getIds` on parent class  Room (because `p.getId()` is unknown for the compiler because the missing type info).

Minimal example with all classes here http://pastebin.com/fL4JcGLj

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not be able to fully understand your intent, but the following generic base class would do what you describe:

```
class Room<T> {
   protected playersById : PlayerDict<T>;

   getFirst() {
      return _.first(this.playersById);
   }
}

class PlayerRoom extends Room<Player> {
    getIds() {
      _.map(this.playersById, (p : Player) => { return p.getId() })
   }
}

class RoomGame extends Room<PlayerGame> {
   someMethod() {
      var player = this.getFirst();
      player.getB();
   }
}
```

This means your original `Room` is actually called `PlayerRoom` in my example (although you could name them however you like).

This allows you to share the appropriate methods such as `getFirst` but have methods reliant on the type of `PlayerDict` in the sub-classes.

Update

Here is the amended version that promotes the `getIds()` method to the base class...

```
interface HasId {
    getId(): number;
}

class Room<T extends HasId> {
   protected playersById : PlayerDict<T>;

   getFirst() {
      return _.first(this.playersById);
   }

    getIds() {
      _.map(this.playersById, (p : T) => { return p.getId(); })
   }
}

class PlayerRoom extends Room<Player> {

}

class RoomGame extends Room<PlayerGame> {
   someMethod() {
      var player = this.getFirst();
      player.getB();
   }
}
```

Comment: But in your example `RoomGame` is not extending from `Room<Player>` so doesn't have `getIds` method. I think that the solution is to use parametric classes with constraints to `Player` type on the base class.

Comment: I have added an example that promotes that method to the base class - it uses a generic type constraint to ensure that it will only work with types that have a `getId` method.